# Use matchMedia to enable/disable script like a media query on load/viewport resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, matchmedia

I only want to run a script when the viewport width is greater than a set value. I would also like this to check as the browser resizes and disable/enable as required. I've tried to achieve this using `matchMedia` and rather than checking every pixel, the script only triggers when the viewport is less/greater than a set value.

If I load a narrow viewport (less than 1080px) the JS doesn't trigger - perfect! Enlarging the viewport to have a width greater than 1080px then runs the script - also perfect!

The problem I have is when I scale down from a larger viewport (greater than 1080px) to narrow/small. The script still functions until I refresh the page - I'm hoping someone can help me with that.

As an aside, is it possible to change `const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1080px)')`  to include a min-height or a more complex media query if required (not essential for this).

My script:

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1080px)')

function viewportChange(e) {
  // Check if the media query is true
  if (e.matches) {
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
      var num_children = $('.split-loop__left').children().length;
      var child_height = $('.split-loop__right').height() / num_children;
      var half_way = num_children * child_height / 2;
      $(window).scrollTop(half_way);
    
      function crisscross() {
          
          var parent = $(".split-loop");//.first();
          var clone = $(parent).clone();
          
          var leftSide = $(clone).find('.split-loop__left');
          var rightSide = $(clone).find('.split-loop__right');
    
          if (window.scrollY > half_way ) {
              //We are scrolling up
              $(window).scrollTop(half_way - child_height);
              
              var firstLeft = $(leftSide).children().first();
              var lastRight = $(rightSide).children().last();
              
              lastRight.appendTo(leftSide);
              firstLeft.prependTo(rightSide);
    
          } else if (window.scrollY < half_way - child_height) {
    
              var lastLeft = $(leftSide).children().last();
              var firstRight = $(rightSide).children().first();
              
              $(window).scrollTop(half_way);
              lastLeft.appendTo(rightSide);
              firstRight.prependTo(leftSide);
          }
    
          $(leftSide).css('bottom', '-' + window.scrollY + 'px');
          $(rightSide).css('bottom', '-' + window.scrollY + 'px');
    
          $(parent).replaceWith(clone);        
      }
      
      $(window).scroll(crisscross);
    
    });
  }
}

// Register event listener
mediaQuery.addListener(viewportChange)

// Initial check
viewportChange(mediaQuery)
```